# Minimal Angular 2 example, necessary classes and HTML

Tags: angular

I read a lot of "quickstart" tutorials. Not a single tutorial shows really minimal and working app.

I have some background in working with Web applications. Several years ago I just add script tags for my code and stone libraries. It was obvious how it works.

Now there is typescript and Angular 2 on bleeding edge of frontend in Web. I had some experience with previous Angular, so I believe it's really good.

I solved some problems with es6 typings in typescript. (Weird problems for all-defaults install.) I more or less understood how I *transpile* into JavaScript.

I believe it's no more than 2 files (HTML and TS), 10 lines each, are needed for minimal, very basic example. With `<script>` tags within  `<head>`. (Not a single tutorial shows how to connect script to HTML file!) Please, show me them. No configs, bunch of CLI tools, complex directory structure. I have `tsc` tool and web server serving static content.

Comment: Have you checked our documentation section? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

This website contains lots of good examples: 
http://angular2-first-look.azurewebsites.net

These examples are from a course of Pluralsight : https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-first-look/table-of-contents

This course compared some core concepts in angular2 with angular1.X. I think it is suit for you since you had some experience with previous Angular.

Pluralsight is good website to learn angular2. I also recommend a course called "Angular 2: Getting Started" on this website.

Hope that helps.